# python bar graph and line graph in same chart with pandas & matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

in a pandas dataframe I have daily stock volume [bar] and a 65 day moving average of the same [line]. I would like them overlayed on one another but cannot figure out how to do it. Can someone please show me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it

Random data

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=100, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng).cumsum()
```

Barchart with 10-day moving average line.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = ts.plot(kind="bar")   # barchart
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), pd.rolling_mean(ts, 10)) #linechart
```

[image]

Comment: thanks.  but how is it possible that the peak of moving average  exceeds the peak if vertical bars?

Comment: this code didn't work.  ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), ts.rolling(10).mean()) worked.